# How to call external functions from react components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pixi.js

I am developing a game with Pixi.js library and decided to use React for the UI layer.

I am struggling with finding a good way to make them work together. For example: user clicks and undo button(rendered with react) and undo action should happen inside of the game.

My first thought was to use a state management library, but that doesn't make sense because most actions don't have any state at all, just 'New game', 'Restart game' and etc.

What I've come up with is to save globally a ref to my main react component, and then set callbacks to it and to pass them down the react tree. Like that:

```
<UI ref={(component) => (window.UI = component)} />
window.UI.setUndoListener(() => game.undo())
```

And my UI Component:

```
export default class UI extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = {
      onUndo: null,
      onNewGame: null,
      onRestartGame: null,
    }
  }

  setNewGameListener(fn) {
    this.setState({ onNewGame: fn })
  }

  setRestartGameListener(fn) {
    this.setState({ onRestartGame: fn })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Menu
          onNewGame={this.state.onNewGame}
          onRestartGame={this.state.onRestartGame}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

But this feels very not right and I feel like there should be a better way to do it. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you use canvas tech it is bad to mix html UI or react . Make clear react only for Message box or table or hud elements. Don't mix , react have a lot strict roles...

Comment: Don't use shortcut like global's.You will need top root class App or Game in that class put all sub component in component put there elements etc.(Now you can use props and state , customEvents ... )  If you don't have top root class all staff goes crazy.

Comment: Is your Pixi.js canvas inside of the React app, or outside? Are you using React only for the UI and Pixi.js only for the graphics? In that case... why even use React? I'm struggling to find a reason you would involve React just for some simple UI when you could easily accomplish that with some vanilla JavaScript...

Comment: I am using react only for UI. At first it seemed like a nice idea to do all the UI with html/css, because that's why these tech exist. And basically, I just wanted to play around with react :) I will finish this game with what I have achieved already, but for future projects, I think I will stick with UI in Pixi.